# Is the inner SELECT statement replaceable by a JOIN statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, select

I work very frequently with timeseries and process an enormous amount of data. The data are in a SQL Server database and are queried with the following query:

```
SELECT  id, published_date, value_date, value
FROM    timeseries t1
WHERE   t1.id = 1011
        AND t1.value_date BETWEEN '2017-01-07 00:00:00' AND '2019-09-15 15:00:00'
        AND t1.published_date = (
                                SELECT  MAX(t2.published_date)
                                FROM    timeseries t2
                                WHERE   t2.published_date <= '2019-09-21 23:59:59'
                                        AND t2.id = t1.id
                                        AND t2.value_date = t1.value_date
                                )
ORDER   BY t1.value_date
```

The above query returns exactly the data I need. In fact, the query gives me the last published data for a given period (`value_date`). However, the problem is that if the period becomes very large, the query takes a long time. The reason is that there are several publications (`published_date`) for the period.

I'm sure it has to do with the inner SELECT statement, since it searches row by row for the maximum published_date. My attempts to improve/accelerate the query with a JOIN statement did not work.

How would you modify the SQL query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't do anything until AFTER you have examined the actual execution plan to understand how the data is accessed and why it is "slow". What exactly does "period becomes very large" mean? And this `'2019-09-21 23:59:59'` is a logic error waiting to be discovered - that time value is likely not the "largest" possible value for your datatype. Use boundary that is exclusive.

Comment: Are you even certain that the problem is wholly within the engine and not with the consumer of your resultset or the transmission over the network?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure that it has something to do with the query and nothing to do with the network. I tried the same query in SQLite and got approximately the same query time (of cource with same indexes).

Comment: @SMor Regarding your first post: You probably didn't understand the logic behind published_date.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your logic using a join:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.published_date, t1.value_date, t1.value
FROM timeseries t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, value_date, MAX(published_date) AS max_published_date
    FROM timeseries
    WHERE published_date <= '2019-09-21 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY id, value_date
) t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id AND
       t2.value_date = t1.value_date AND
       t2.max_published_date = t1.published_date
WHERE
    t1.id = 1011 AND
    t1.value_date BETWEEN '2017-01-07 00:00:00' AND '2019-09-15 15:00:00'
ORDER BY
    t1.value_date;
```

However, the bigger issue here from the performance point of view might be that you don't have any indexes on the `timeseries` table.  Try adding the following index for improved performance:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON timeseries (id, value_date, published_date);
```

This index should make the subquery aliased as `t2` run very fast.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your post. Yes, I'm using indices. Unfortunately, your suggested query takes about twice as long as mine.

Comment: @grima Can you try my query with the index `(id, value_date, published_date)` ?

Comment: I was using exactly the same index pair with the result that it takes twice as long as mine.

Comment: Then maybe you should stick with your current query.

Comment: I would suggest your t2 query ALSO have the time limit on its "id = 1011" and value_date to also match the outer query value_date, such as the 2017-01-07 to 2019-09-15.  So it is not querying the entire range of data that falls out of the range they are looking.  Show knows if the data is going back to early 2000's or prior.  You are otherwise pre-aggregating things that will never qualify.  That is probably where the performance is failing in comparison.

Comment: @DRapp Thanks for your advice. Doing so it is as fast as mine.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use max()over() window function with condition then using common table expression you can compare published_date with max_published_date

```
with cte as 
(
  SELECT  id, published_date, value_date, value, 
          max(case when published_date <= '2019-09-21 23:59:59' then published_date end)over(partition by id,value_date)max_publish_date
  FROM    timeseries t1
  WHERE   t1.id = 1011
          AND t1.value_date BETWEEN '2017-01-07 00:00:00' AND '2019-09-15 15:00:00'
  ORDER   BY t1.value_date
select id, published_date, value_date, value from cte where published_date=max_publish_date
```

Comment: This is as fast as Tim's suggestion.

Comment: @grima Normally this is faster than a self-join. An index on `id, value_date` would be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.published_date, t1.value_date, t1.value
FROM timeseries t1 
INNER JOIN timeseries t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                         AND t2.value_date = t1.value_date
WHERE t1.id = 1011 
  AND t1.value_date BETWEEN '2017-01-07 00:00:00' AND '2019-09-15 15:00:00' 
  AND t2.published_date <= '2019-09-21'
HAVING t1.published_date = MAX(t2.published_date)
ORDER BY t1.value_date;
```

Comment: The query could not be executed because it was terminated with the message "a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING".